# What is the difference between "complice"and "accomplice"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the difference between "complice" and "accomplice"?

Both means an associate person during some act or something.

But what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that no one says *complice*. I didn't even know it was a word until I looked it up just now.  [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/com%C2%B7plice) lists *complice* as *archaic*.

> **com·plice**  (kmpls)
>   n. *Archaic*
>
> An associate; an accomplice.

Just use *accomplice*.

Comment: So, does it mean that only highly educated people will understand and this word is reserved for the academia soil?

Comment: @Derfder I'm not sure it would even be used in academia. *Archaic* doesn't really mean it's used in academia; it means it's pretty much never used. Though it's worth mentioning that the similar word [complicit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complicit) is actually quite common.

Comment: Some fiction will use archaic words in order to sound old or alien. @WendiKidd is right that "accomplice" has completely replaced "complice" in normal speech.